# Discharging MOSFET using Resistance or Diode (Best possible Alternate)

Tags: led, mosfet, resistors, sensor

I have two Questions about MOSFET as sensor device.

**1.** I had been using resistance to discharge MOSFET. but I can not figure out minimum requirement of the resistance which could work on 12V power supply?
[image]

**2.** Can I use diode to discharge MOSFET? as given in following circuit diagram..

[image: Diode for discharging MOSFET]

Comment: How do you expect that diode to conduct? Resistor value you need depends on how fast you want it to turn off vs. how much current you can afford to waste from the battery to keep the MOSFET gate charged.

Comment: Could you please draw your circuit with the ground below and power above? Your way of drawing gives me a headache. And what is R3 doing at that location, and why 220k?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen haha! sorry for the Circuit diagram. R3 (Resistance - 220 ohm or 0.220k not 220K) is to protect LED.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen if you look close its actually 0.220K...

Comment: @Trevor Can you please suggest minimum Resistance required to discharge using 12V Battery? my main concern is both positive and negative terminal of battery are disconnected with only resistance. does it hurt battery ?

Comment: HUH? Me thinks you are totally confused.

Comment: Also take a look at this question. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/20510/determine-mosfet-switching-speed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok lets draw your circuit properly...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foSlfV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now lets say when the switch is closed you only want 0.1mA of current to be wasted.

\$R2 = 12V/0.1mA = 120K\$

Now, from the data-sheet an IRF530 has a max gate capacitance of 800pF. So the gate will discharge exponentially with an RC time constant of 9.6uS when the switch opens.

That seems fast enough to me...

Maybe you want 1uA... R would be 12Meg and that would put the time constant close to 1mS.